Insecure hashing algorithm SHA1 , MD5 used AppSweep issue
We are trying to integrate dexguard on our application. while we generate the protected .apk file and uploaded to app sweep we got an issue Insecure hashing algorithm SHA1 used  and Insecure hashing algorithm MD5 used from
com.google.firebase.installations.local.IidStore ,
com.google.android.gms.common.util.AndroidUtilsLight ,
okio.ByteString and
org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto library files.


I tried below codes added on dexguard rules files and fount its not working,
-keep class org.conscrypt.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.util.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.common.hash.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.** { *; }
-keep class okio.** { *; }

